# Changing values in a spreadsheet from HTML page

Tags: html, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having difficulties creating an HTML page with a custom GUI that displays data from a spreadsheet that can be edited.

A simple example, let's say we have one value in our spreadsheet "Sheet1" in the location "A1" and it Says "Hello", that's it. Then on the webpage a textfield appears where the "Hello" has been set to that text-input field, so now you can change the text to let's say "Ohoy" and next to the input field there is a button that says "Save" and then it set's the corresponding cell in the spreadsheet "A1" to what is entered in the input field, "Ohoy" in this case

Anyone who could help me with this? I have read that people have done it, I just can't quite figure out the ecact coding of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a function in appscript, as well as the html to display the input field.

In GS (Google AppScript), you will need a function to display the HTML, as well as another one to set the values sent from the input field (editContents).
Here is the code for the gs:

```
function doGet()
{
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function editContents(text)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID_of_your_Spreadsheet");
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  activeCell.setValue(text);
}
```

In your Html, you only need the input and a button. Use google.script.run to access the functions defined in gs.

```
<html>
  <body>
  <input type="text" name="text" id='txtEdit'><br>
  <input type="button" value="Save"
  onclick="google.script.run.editContents(document.getElementById('txtEdit').value)">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me alot! What I lack now is to prefill the text in the inputfield with the value in the spreadsheet?