# Uncaught ReferenceError google is not defined (spreadsheet) on HTML?

Tags: javascript, web, spreadsheet, referenceerror

I want to do a web page, with Google Spreadsheet as storage, and I need to upload some cells, just [like in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32279123/changing-values-in-a-spreadsheet-from-html-page)

But when I do that it gives me one of these errors

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

or

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick

I assume I have to put some reference, but I do not know how to get it.

Comment: Are you editing in the Scripts Manager for Google Sheets or trying to use their API in your own editor?

Comment: If using your own editor, you'll need to install the GoogleApi package (`npm install googleapi --save`) and `require` it into the project. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis

Comment: I am currently working only with the Google Sheets command editor. But for this case I think I need to use the API

Comment: Can you paste a sample of the code where the error is happening?